# AndroidManfest missing from new Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Created one Android application project in eclipse and whenever I tried to run that application its throwing an error message saying **AndroidManifest.xml** file is missing.

What is the reason for this?

How do I add **AndroidManifest.xml** to my Android project.?

Comment: how do i add androidmanifest.xml to my android project. i am just doing my first project(My First App). plz help me with this.

Comment: Your question really confusing, in which IDE you are trying to create project Android Studio or Eclipse?. Because your question title showing Android Studio but you asking about in Eclipse.

Comment: @ Shashanth  eclipse

Comment: It's 2016 better to use Android Studio instead of Eclipse. now Android Studio is official editor for Android app development.

Comment: +1 @Shashanth , you should Android Studio, start here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Comment: If you actually created a brand new Android project and didn't delete any files, the Manifest is there, but yes, as of 2016 Eclipse ADT is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you had in the previous manifest.xml many changes. If this is not the case, just create other project, copy all the files, and that's all. If this is not the case, try with a backup, if you don't have one, then try to remember what you had, because there is no more ways.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that in eclipse you are developing app on android not in java.

   2. Try making a new Project and compile it without any coding to see if error comes again or not.
   3. Go for android studios because its used for android apps development.